# setState never gets set in useEffect after API call responds with data

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to update state immediately after data comes in from the API. The data is coming in, I can see it using the console.log right below my API request. All of the data is right but for some reason, setState never sets in my hook. It just returns and empty array even after the console displays data.

```
const [experienceData, setExperienceData] = useState([]);

const { match = {} } = props;

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            if (Object.keys(match.params).length > 0) {
                const response = await ApiService.getExperiences(match.params.experieneId);
                console.log(response)
                setExperienceData(response)
            }
        }
        fetchData();
    }, []);
```

I must be doing something wrong but I can't figure out what that is. Hoping someone on here has run into the same issue.

UPDATE: I just changed everything over the a class and duplicated the exact code on another file and ran into the exact same issue. The console updates with the data, but the setState on the line immediately after the data does not setState.

```
async componentDidMount() {
        if (Object.keys(this.props.match.params).length > 0) {
            const response = await ApiService.getExperiences(this.props.match.params.experieneId);
            console.log(response[0])
            this.setState({ experienceData: response[0], occurrenceData: response[0].occurrences });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide `[props.match.params]` or `[props.match.params.experieneId]` as second argument to `useEffect` instead of an empty array?

Comment: can you try to convert to `json`first before setting the response. Add `let r = response.json(); console.log(r); setExperienceData(r)`. set the value of `r` in the hook. Add these lines after `console.log(response)`.

Comment: It's not a json error, I've been able to pull throughout the rest of the app using classes.

Comment: can you share your code through codesandbox

Comment: I can't connect up the API so I don't think there's anything I can show you that I'm not already.

Comment: This is how I'm navigating from the previous view: this.props.history.push({
            pathname: `/booked/${this.props.experienceData.id}/${this.props.occurrence.id}`
        });

Comment: can you share the code for the method `getExperiences`

Comment: I don't think that has anythign to do with this, I have this exact same code working in another class component. And the data is displaying in the console right in useEffect and componentDidMount.

Answer (score 1):

You have to useSetState in a proper way, the issue is in the setExperienceData

```
const [experienceData, setExperienceData] = useState({response:""});

const { match = {} } = props;

useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
        if (Object.keys(props.match.params).length > 0) {
            const response = await ApiService.getExperiences(match.params.experieneId);
            console.log(response)
            setExperienceData(experienceData => ({ ...experienceData, response: response }));
        }
    }
    fetchData();
}, []);
return(<div>check {experienceData.response}</div>)
```

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work either. I'm still getting the same console results, a lot of empty responses, only the console.log in the if statement displays the data at the very end, then nothing else is displayed and the sate doesn't appear to have changed.

Comment: @MattBrody no need to afraid for that, just post your issue in some online code editor. We will look into it :)

Answer (score 0):

I see you left the dependency array empty. This tells React to run this effect only once: when the component first renders. If you want your `useEffect` to respect your state hook, put `setExperienceData` inside the dependency array

Comment: I just tried it, [setExperienceData], but nothing changed.

Comment: Try adding `props.match.params` also as nishkaush suggested then.

Comment: That didn't fix it either

Comment: Could you provide a more complete version of your code?

Comment: you will need `[match.params]` as the second argument to useEffect or it won't work.

Comment: There's a ton to it, this is just a small bit. I think I'm just going to make this a class for now since I have no problem getting that to work.

Comment: The thing I don't understand is why console.log works at the very end. It's empty until the last time and then the data is there in the console but the state isn't updated.

Comment: Is the function `ApiService.getExperiences()` asynchronous indeed?

Answer (score 0):

```
const [experienceData, setExperienceData] = useState([]);

const { match = {} } = props;

useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
}, [props.match.params]);

const async fetchData = () => {
  if (Object.keys(match.params).length > 0) {
    const response = await ApiService.getExperiences(match.params.experieneId);
    console.log(response)
    setExperienceData([...response])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try passing `[match.params]` as the second argument to your useEffect.